Odoo Blank page after migration
I have migrated my Odoo database from version 15.0 to 17.0 using the upgrade.py script. All related addons have also been migrated. After the migration, I executed the command odoo-bin -u all --stop-after-init​ and waited until the update process completed successfully.
However, after restarting the Odoo service and trying to access the web interface, I am greeted with a blank page, as shown in the attached screenshot.
Here are the steps I followed in detail:

Backup: I took a complete backup of my database and addons before starting the migration process.

Upgrade Script: I used the upgrade.py script to migrate the database from Odoo 15.0 to 17.0.

Addons Migration: Ensured that all custom and third-party addons were compatible with Odoo 17.0 and migrated them accordingly.

Update Command: Ran the command odoo-bin -u all --stop-after-init  to update all modules after the migration.

Restart: Restarted the Odoo service using systemctl restart odoo (or the equivalent command).


Despite following these steps, I am facing the issue of a blank page

